# PayPal SDK request for access token returns code 401 (unauthorized)

Tags: swift, curl, oauth-2.0, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to receive an access token from PayPal's server using the authorization code in a Sandbox environment. I believe the problem is in converting curl to an Alamofire request, but I'm not sure. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code for sending authorization to server:

```
func sendAuthorizationToServer(authorization: [AnyHashable: Any]) {

    let jsonAuth = JSON(authorization)

    let headers = [
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
    ]
    let parameters = [
        "client_id": Constants.payPalSandboxID,
        "client_secret": Constants.payPalSandboxSecret,
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "redirect_uri": "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
        "code": jsonAuth["response"]["code"].stringValue
    ]

    Alamofire.request("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        print(response.request)
        print(response.response)
        print(response.data)
        print(response.error)
        }
}
```

I've checked `jsonAuth["response"]["code"].stringValue` and it is returning a correct authorization code.
My doubts are if it should be a `.post` request or a `.get` request, and if my credentials in the parameters are in the correct order/structure.

Here is the output of the last print statements:

[image]
Here is the SDK link for exchanging an authorization code for the access token:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/future_payments_server.md#exchange-authorization-code-for-refresh--access-tokens

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire

// ... ...
// ... ...
// ... ...


let credentialData = "\(paypalClientId):\(paypalSecret)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
let headers = [
    "Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)",
]
let params:[String: Any] = [
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
]
Alamofire.request(tokenAPI, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
    .validate()
    .responseJSON { (response) in
        debugPrint(response)
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let data):
             let json = JSON(data)
             let accessToken = json["access_token"].stringValue
             break;
        case .failure(let error):
             debugPrint(error)
             debugPrint(response.data)
        }
    }
```

> Please note that encoding must be URLEncoding.default not the JSONEncoding.default